# using a digital pin on node mcu as an analog

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, sensors, current, voltage

i want to use volte and current sensors (ZMPT101B and ACS712) on node MCU these sensors are analog but node mcu has on analog pin can i use digital D0 pin for voltage sensor?

Comment: yes, but the resolution is one bit.

Comment: @dandavis I was about to respond with NO but yours is better.

Comment: @dandavis lol ... your comment stirred a few memory cells ... more than one bit resolution is possible ... google `1-bit ADC`

Comment: @mohamedmansour you can use one digital input if you use some external circuitry ... monitor the output of a comparator ... the two comparator inputs would be, the voltage input and an programmable reference voltage ... for example, suppose full scale is 6 V and you have an input of 4 V ... first you compare the input to 3 V and record  `1` ... next compare to 3 + 1.5 V and record a `0` ... next you roll back the 1.5 V and compare to 3 + 0.75 V and record a `1`  ... next compare 3 + 0.75 + 0.375 V and record a `0`  ....... so far the digital data is `1010` .... you can keep going for more bits

Comment: use an I2C ADC module. they have usualy at least 4 ADC pins.